# How to get the cell with the highest number, work with it, get the next highest and so on in excel?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to get a cell with value `BBBBBBBGGGGGJJJJCCCCDDDDAA` from these cells:

```
-----------------------------------------
| 2 | 7 | 4 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
-----------------------------------------
```

So it gets the highest value and writes the cell's horizontal address (that might have an offset) that many times. Then gets the next highest and does the same thing until it reaches the zeroes. Is that possible in excel?

additional samples:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | GGGGGDDDAA                               |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | GGGGGCC                                  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0 | 7 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | BBBBBBBEEEEFFFGGGCCDD                    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4 | 7 | 0 | 7 | 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 7 | IIIIIIIIBBBBBBBDDDDDDDEEEEEEEJJJJJJJAAAA |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 0 | 2 | 0 | 2 | 8 | 0 | 8 | 0 | 7 | 10| JJJJJJJJJJEEEEEEEEGGGGGGGGIIIIIIIBBDD    |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Provide more sample data set.

Comment: I'm missing the part where the `A` 's are explained.

Comment: @Jeeped Oh I forgot the horizontal address was entirely letters. A was supposed to be 10, but now I'll edit it so it starts from A instead of 1.